# Generic java interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am new to Generics. I would like to write an interface `SearchableFruit` for many "fruit" classes like:

```
public interface SearchableFruit<T>{
    //returns a list of newer fruit object than current fruit object
    public static List<T> searchNewerFruit(T curr); 
}
```

So I could use this interface for classes `Apple` and `Orange`:

```
public class Apple implements SearchableFruit{
    public static List<Apple> searchNewerFruit(Apple currentApple){
    //TODO get apples newers than currentApple
    //return a list of Apples
}

}
```

I never done an interface before and this is not working for me, can you clarify me how should I write it properly?

Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933156/java-generics-and-interfaces

Comment: Note: interfaces can't have static methods.

Comment: `public class Apple implements SearchableFruit<Apple>`

Comment: Be specific about what kinds of suggestions do you want!

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis. I got it now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this

```
public interface SearchableFruit<T>{
    public List<T> searchNewerFruit(T curr); 
}

public class Apple implements SearchableFruit<Apple> {
    public List<Apple> searchNewerFruit(Apple currentApple){
        // impl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, interfaces can not contains static methods.
Second, you miss type in implementation. Correct:

```
public class Apple implements SearchableFruit<Apple>{
    public List<Apple> searchNewerFruit(Apple currentApple){
    //TODO get apples newers than currentApple
    //return a list of Apples
}

}
```

Comment: ctrl+c ctrl+v pattern... ech...